# BeginUmbracoForm not rendering action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm try to create simple login form using mvc umbraco, however its not hitting controller as BeginUmbracoForm is not outputting action name. Unable to figure out why its not.

Below is my code

**View**

```
 <h3> Login</h3>

                @using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SubmitLogin", "Login", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { id = "login" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "alert text-danger" })
                    <form>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="required">*</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control input-md0", required = "required", type = "email" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <!-- Text input-->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })<span class="required">*</span>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control input-md", required = "required", type = "password" })
                        </div>

                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary()
                            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
                            <a href="forget-password.html" class="pull-right"> <small>Forgot Password ?</small></a>
                        </div>
                    </form>




                }
```

**Controller**

```
 public class LoginController : SurfaceController
    {

        // GET: /Login/     
        public ActionResult RenderLogin()
        {
            var model =new  LoginModel();
          return  PartialView("~/Views/Partials/Forms/LoginForm.cshtml", model);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("SubmitLogin")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SubmitLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
                    UrlHelper myHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Request.RequestContext);
                    if (myHelper.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect("/login/");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
            return CurrentUmbracoPage();
        }

}
```

**Html Output**

```
<form action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="login" method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<LoginController>("SubmitLogin", new { id = "login" })) {

}
```

It would also be worth reviewing the `BeginUmbracoForm` overloads and documentation here:

https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/Forms